# How to - Connect Xbox controller using Bluetooth

Tags: linux, bluetooth

If you try to connect a Bluetooth capable Xbox controller to a Linux device, chances are that it won't work, you'll see the connection state flip continuously between connected and disconnected without ever successfully connecting.

This connection state flipping is accompanied by a blinking white light on the controller.

I found [this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/xbox-one-controllers-over-bluetooth-linux/) which has a solution that worked for me, I'm going to document it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Temporary

1. Remove the controller from the "remembered devices" section of your Blueooth management software.
2. Run

   ```
   echo Y | sudo tee /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm
   ```
3. Connect to the controller.

> **This is temporary, rebooting your computer will undo the effect of step 2**

> *There is also a permanent solution in the linked article, but I didn't use that and so I haven't included it in this answer, if anyone does use it, and it works, feel free to add it here.*

[source](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/xbox-one-controllers-over-bluetooth-linux/)

### Permanent

1. Edit

   ```
   /etc/modprobe.d/xbox_bt.conf
   ```
2. Add this to the file

   ```
   options bluetooth disable_ertm=1
   ```
3. Reboot your computer.
4. Observe that `/sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm` is `Y`.

[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gamepad#Xbox_Wireless_Controller_/_Xbox_One_Wireless_Controller)

### Notes

You may need to run the following command at the end to make things work.

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```